# Multiple NSTimers in swift do not work

Tags: swift, xcode7

I have multiple NSTimers in a program because I need them to change the value of a label after they are done. However, every time I set it up, it just skips down to the last one I created. I have been looking through this forum and have not found anything yet that was just like my situation, so I have put in the code below.
I am using xcode 7 and swift 2.0.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Mobile Streaming Countdown
//
//  Created by Benjamin Peterson on 10/11/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Ben Peterson. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {




@IBOutlet var imageview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var loadimage: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var step1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var step2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var oneminute: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tenminutes: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var startingsoon: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var steo3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var starttimer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var numberOfMinutes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var minutes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ThreeMinutes: UIButton!




let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

var tNumberOfMinutes = 0
var timer = NSTimer()
var timer2 = NSTimer()
var timer3 = NSTimer()
var timer4 = NSTimer()
var timer5 = NSTimer()
let timeInterval:NSTimeInterval = 10.0
var timeCount:NSTimeInterval = 10.0

let secondscountdown = 0


@IBAction func loadImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageview.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageview.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func oneMinute(sender: AnyObject) {
    tNumberOfMinutes = 1
}
func timeString(time:NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60
    //let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    let seconds = time - Double(minutes) * 60
    let secondsFraction = seconds - Double(Int(seconds))
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i.%01i",minutes,Int(seconds),Int(secondsFraction * 10.0))
}
func timerDidEnd(timer:NSTimer){
    //first iteration of timer
    numberOfMinutes.text = "Ready!!"
}
func timerTwo(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "1"
}
func timerThree(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "2"
}
func timerFour(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "3"
}
func timerFive(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "4"
}
func timerSix(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "5"
}
func timerSeven(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "6"
}
func timerEight(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "7"
}
func timerNine(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "8"
}
func timerTen(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "9"
}

@IBAction func tenMinutes(sender: AnyObject) {
    tNumberOfMinutes = 10
}
@IBAction func startingsoon(sender: AnyObject) {
    tNumberOfMinutes = 11
}
@IBAction func threeMinutes(sender: AnyObject) {
    tNumberOfMinutes = 5
}





@IBAction func startTimer(sender: AnyObject) {
    if tNumberOfMinutes > 0 {

        step1.hidden = true
        step2.hidden = true
        loadimage.hidden = true
        oneminute.hidden = true
        tenminutes.hidden = true
        startingsoon.hidden = true
        steo3.hidden = true
        starttimer.hidden = true


        if tNumberOfMinutes == 1 {

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerDidEnd:",
                userInfo: "Pizza Done!",
                repeats: false)


        }
        if tNumberOfMinutes == 5 {
            //Part one is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerTwo:",
                userInfo: "this!",
                repeats: false)

            //Second Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerThree:",
                userInfo: "is",
                repeats: false)

            //Third Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerFour:",
                userInfo: "a",
                repeats: false)

            //Fourth Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerFive:",
                userInfo: "test",
                repeats: false)

            //Fifth Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerSix:",
                userInfo: "to",
                repeats: false)
        }
        if tNumberOfMinutes == 10 {
            //Part one is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerTwo:",
                userInfo: "see",
                repeats: false)

            //Second Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerThree:",
                userInfo: "if changing",
                repeats: false)

            //Third Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerFour:",
                userInfo: "these fixes",
                repeats: false)

            //Fourth Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerFive:",
                userInfo: "the",
                repeats: false)

            //Fifth Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerSix:",
                userInfo: "problems",
                repeats: false)
            //Part one is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerSeven:",
                userInfo: "in",
                repeats: false)

            //Second Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerEight:",
                userInfo: "the",
                repeats: false)

            //Third Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerNine:",
                userInfo: "code",
                repeats: false)

            //Fourth Part is starting here

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerTen:",
                userInfo: "derple",
                repeats: false)

            //Fifth Part is starting here

            //timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval,
                //target: self,
                //selector: "timerDidEnd:",
                //userInfo: "flerple",
                //repeats: false)
        }
        if tNumberOfMinutes == 11 {
            numberOfMinutes.text = ("Show is starting soon!")
            minutes.hidden = true

        }
    }



}
```

}

I do not use the timers 2-5, and plan to get rid of them, but I wanted to include them to show that I tried assigning each of the scheduled time with time intervals, but that didn't work either.

Thanks for your help in advance!

- Jargames

Comment: Please post the full code. How do you start the timer?

Comment: with an IBAction, then the scheduledTimerWithInterval starts the rest

Comment: you are steting them all to the same global timer variable.  Thats why you only get the last one because it's overwriting the previous timer.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your answer! Can you please give an example code on how to fix this?

Comment: According to the documentation: "Because the run loop maintains the timer, from the perspective of object lifetimes there’s typically no need to keep a reference to a timer after you’ve scheduled it."

Comment: @Darko So would you recommend that I set repeats to true? If so, what should I do so it only runs five times? And also, how would I make it so that it changes the label every time I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are firing but because the timer-handler methods all are changing the same variable you just see the last one firing.

So:

timerTwo sets text to 1 (then immediately afterwards)

timerThree sets text to 2...

etc...

etc...

timerNine sets text to 8

timerTen sets text to 9

Because all of this happens very fast you just see the last result.

Put in a print(x) in each of the handler methods and you should see all of them called one after another.

```
func timerTwo(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "1"
    print("timerTwo")
}

func timerThree(timer:NSTimer) {
    numberOfMinutes.text = "2"
    print("timerThree")
}

/// etc...
```

So basically it is just a logic-problem.

Comment: I see what you mean now, and it is very useful, but how would I keep each one from delaying? Would using the sleep function from importing darwin help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like each NSTimer to execute one after the other, in order. And thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: If you want that the timers are firing in 10 second intervals then you could just start the next timer inside the handler method of the previous.

Comment: Or you could start the first timer with 10 sec and the second with 20, etc..,

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I appreciate it so much.